# CMake Error while using find_package(Boost ... ) in CMakeLists.txt: No suitable build variant has been found

Tags: boost, cmake

When using CMake, I get the following error when calling `find_package(Boost 1.6 COMPONENTS program_options thread system REQUIRED)`:

```
-- Boost include dirs: C:/dev/boost/include/boost-1_72
-- Boost libraries:
Boost library
-- Found Boost 1.72.0 at C:/dev/boost/lib/cmake/Boost-1.72.0
--   Requested configuration: QUIET REQUIRED COMPONENTS program_options;thread;system
-- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_headers 1.72.0 EXACT CONFIG REQUIRED QUIET HINTS C:/dev/boost/lib/cmake)
-- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_program_options 1.72.0 EXACT CONFIG REQUIRED QUIET HINTS C:/dev/boost/lib/cmake)
-- Found boost_program_options 1.72.0 at C:/dev/boost/lib/cmake/boost_program_options-1.72.0
-- Boost toolset is vc142 (MSVC 19.25.28612.0)
-- Scanning C:/dev/boost/lib/cmake/boost_program_options-1.72.0/libboost_program_options-variant*.cmake
--   Including C:/dev/boost/lib/cmake/boost_program_options-1.72.0/libboost_program_options-variant-vc142-mt-gd-x32-1_72-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_program_options-vc142-mt-gd-x32-1_72.lib
--   Including C:/dev/boost/lib/cmake/boost_program_options-1.72.0/libboost_program_options-variant-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_72-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_program_options-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_72.lib
--   Including C:/dev/boost/lib/cmake/boost_program_options-1.72.0/libboost_program_options-variant-vc142-mt-x32-1_72-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_program_options-vc142-mt-x32-1_72.lib
--   Including C:/dev/boost/lib/cmake/boost_program_options-1.72.0/libboost_program_options-variant-vc142-mt-x64-1_72-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_program_options-vc142-mt-x64-1_72.lib
CMake Error at C:/dev/boost/lib/cmake/Boost-1.72.0/BoostConfig.cmake:120 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    C:/dev/boost/lib/cmake/boost_program_options-1.72.0/boost_program_options-config.cmake

  but it set boost_program_options_FOUND to FALSE so package
  "boost_program_options" is considered to be NOT FOUND.  Reason given by
  package:

  No suitable build variant has been found.

  The following variants have been tried and rejected:

  * libboost_program_options-vc142-mt-gd-x32-1_72.lib (32 bit, need 64)

  * libboost_program_options-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_72.lib (static,
  Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=OFF)

  * libboost_program_options-vc142-mt-x32-1_72.lib (32 bit, need 64)

  * libboost_program_options-vc142-mt-x64-1_72.lib (static,
  Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=OFF)

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/dev/boost/lib/cmake/Boost-1.72.0/BoostConfig.cmake:185 (boost_find_component)
  C:/dev/cmake-3.17.0-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:444 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:79 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/sbreuer/Documents/Uni/Praktikum/SunFlower/Simulation/code/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/sbreuer/Documents/Uni/Praktikum/SunFlower/Simulation/code/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I do not understand the problem here. I added the environment variables for the `include` and the `lib` directory. I am using CMake 3.17.0 and Boost 1.72.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important section of the error is here:

```
  No suitable build variant has been found.

  The following variants have been tried and rejected:

  * libboost_program_options-vc142-mt-gd-x32-1_72.lib (32 bit, need 64)

  * libboost_program_options-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_72.lib (static,
  Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=OFF)

  * libboost_program_options-vc142-mt-x32-1_72.lib (32 bit, need 64)

  * libboost_program_options-vc142-mt-x64-1_72.lib (static,
  Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=OFF)
```

It shows the libraries that were found, and gives the reason why they were rejected. All of the libraries here are *static*, as indicated by the `lib` prefix on their names. However, your CMake configuration indicates you do **not** want to use static libraries (`Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=OFF`). To fix the error, you have two options:

1. Set `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS` to `ON`:

   ```
   set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
   find_package(Boost 1.6 COMPONENTS program_options thread system REQUIRED)
   ```
2. Build the **shared** Boost libraries, so not only the static libraries are available.