# boost_chrono_FOUND to FALSE so package "boost_chrono" is considered to be NOT FOUND

Tags: c++, linux, boost, cmake, rippled

I am trying to build [ripple](https://xrpl.org/build-run-rippled-ubuntu.html) by following the [build guide on GitHub](https://github.com/ripple/rippled), but boost is continuously throwing some unknown error. Boost is installed and running. I installed `boost_1_71_0` as described by the build guide.

```
/home/usman/Downloads/clion-2020.1.2/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /home/usman/Desktop/ripple/rippled
-- Using 4 cores for ExternalProject builds.
-- rippled version: 1.6.0
-- NIH-EP cache path: /home/usman/Desktop/ripple/rippled/.nih_c/unix_makefiles/GNU_9.3.0/Debug
-- using [01bd5a2646cda78ee09d2067c287c8f89872736d] as build container tag...
-- docker local user id: 1000
-- docker local group id: 1000
-- BOOST_ROOT: /usr/local
-- BOOST_LIBRARYDIR: /usr/local/lib/
CMake Error at /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake:117 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_chrono-1.71.0/boost_chrono-config.cmake

  but it set boost_chrono_FOUND to FALSE so package "boost_chrono" is
  considered to be NOT FOUND.  Reason given by package:

  No suitable build variant has been found.

  The following variants have been tried and rejected:

  * libboost_chrono.so.1.71.0 (shared, Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON)

  * libboost_chrono.a (shared runtime, Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME=ON)

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake:182 (boost_find_component)
  Builds/CMake/deps/FindBoost.cmake:273 (find_package)
  Builds/CMake/deps/Boost.cmake:50 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:43 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/usman/Desktop/ripple/rippled/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/usman/Desktop/ripple/rippled/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

[Finished]
```

Comment: What's your cmake file look like?

Comment: @Waqar i am trying to build the project https://github.com/ripple/rippled.git .

Comment: And Cmake version?

Comment: @Waqar it is `3.9.0` as it can be seen here https://github.com/ripple/rippled/blob/develop/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Also, how did you install boost? From your package manager or from source? If the latter, what options did you pass to bootstrap.sh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61145830/3987854), but your issue appears to be the opposite case.

The important section of the error is here:

```
No suitable build variant has been found.

The following variants have been tried and rejected:

* libboost_chrono.so.1.71.0 (shared, Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON)

* libboost_chrono.a (shared runtime, Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME=ON)
```

It shows you what libraries were found, and even gives the reason *why* they were rejected. All of the libraries found on your machine are *shared* libraries. However, your CMake configuration indicates you do **not** want to use shared libraries (`Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON` and `Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME=ON`). To fix the error, you have two options:

1. Set `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS` to `OFF` and `Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME` to `OFF`:

   ```
    set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
    set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
    find_package(Boost ... )
   ```
2. Build the **static** Boost libraries also, so not only the shared libraries are available on your machine.